# Django Reverse with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: django, django-testing

Hi I have an infuriating problem.

I have a url pattern like this:

```
# mproject/myapp.urls.py

url(r'^project/(?P<project_id>\d+)/$','user_profile.views.EditProject',name='edit_project'),
```

it works fine in the browser but for testing, when I do this in the shell:

```
from django.test import Client
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

client= Client()
response = client.get(reverse('edit_project'), project_id=4)
```

I get the dreaded:

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'edit_project' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: in [lastest django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls), reverse is imported from urls. ie `from django.urls import reverse`

Answer (score 369, accepted):

You have to specify `project_id`:

```
reverse('edit_project', kwargs={'project_id':4})
```

Doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse)

Comment: Could you possibly also include how to do this within a template?

Comment: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#url) have examples

Comment: Worked like a cham!

Answer (score 26):

The solution @miki725 is absolutely correct. Alternatively, if you would like to use the `args` attribute as opposed to `kwargs`, then you can simply modify your code as follows:

```py
project_id = 4
reverse('edit_project', args=(project_id,))
```

An example of this can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#examples). This essentially does the same thing, but the attributes are passed as arguments. Remember that any arguments that are passed need to be assigned a value before being reversed. Just use the correct namespace, which in this case is `'edit_project'`.

Answer (score 4):

This problems gave me great headache when i tried to use reverse for generating activation link and send it via email of course. So i think from tests.py it will be same. 
The correct way to do this is following:

```
from django.test import Client
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

#app name - name of the app where the url is defined
client= Client()
response = client.get(reverse('app_name:edit_project', project_id=4))
```

Comment: I just tried this, it doesn't work. @miki725's answer is correct.

Comment: I believe a brace is in the wrong place: response = client.get(reverse('edit_project', project_id=4))

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is by using `kwargs` with `reverse()` function:

```
from django.test import Client
from django.urls import reverse

url = reverse("edit_project", kwargs={"project_id": 4})
response = Client().get(url)
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `resolve_url` is also more straightforward

```
from django.shortcuts import resolve_url

resolve_url('edit_project', project_id=4)
```

[Documentation on this shortcut](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/shortcuts.py#L102)

Comment: respectfully tried and not working for me. im going to stick with reverse. 2018 django 2

Comment: @SebCorbin, literally you do not understand the `resolve` function. Its first parameter is a path not  url_name

Comment: @Wariored thank you for your comment, I noticed I was referring to the wrong function, and it appears it is not documented in the official documentation, only in the source code. Edited to fix this