# django reverse not working with arguments

Tags: python, django

i am trying to use django reverse to route back to a page which take an argument `vendor_id`.

I am trying to do it this way using this post as reference: [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202385/django-reverse-with-arguments-and-keyword-arguments-not-found)

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('vendor_data', kwargs={'vendor_id':vendor_id}))
```

My view method which should be called:

```
def vendorData(request):
    vendors = Vendors()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        vendor_id = request.GET.get('vendor_id')
        if vendors.checkValidVendorId(vendor_id) == False:
            return HttpResponse('<h2>404<br>Invalid Vendor Id.</h2>')
        else:
            vendor_details = vendors.getVendorData(vendor_id)
            .....
            return render(request, 'vendor_data.html', context_dict)
```

my urls.py:

```
url(r'^vendor_data/', views.vendorData, name='vendor_data'),
```

If i dont pass any argument then it shows the HttpResponse from my views method.
If i pass argument `vendor_id` like this:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('vendor_data', kwargs={'vendor_id':vendor_id}))
```

It throws an error. The traceback is:

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Manish\Desktop\ScratcherAdmin\ScratcherAdmin\vendors\views.py" in editVendorData
  162.      return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('vendor_data', kwargs={'vendor_id':vendor_id}))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  579.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  496.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /update_vendor_data/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'vendor_data' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'vendor_id': u'20150001'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['vendor_data/']
```

How to solve this?

Comment: This is because your view doesn't take any argument the same apply to your url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are expecting inside your `view` is a `GET` parameter from `query string`. Something your expected URL should be something like,

```
www.example.com/vendor/?vendor_id=12345
```

And below,

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('vendor_data', kwargs={'vendor_id':vendor_id}))
```

will redirect you to something like,

```
www.example.com/vendor/12345
```

For which your `view` should expect an additional parameter `vendor_id`,

```
def vendorData(request, vendor_id):
```

and accordingly your rest of the code might change.

**Solution to your problem:**

```
return HttpResponseRedirect("{}?vendor_id={}".format(reverse('vendor_data'), vendor_id))
```

Comment: The `url()`  should use captured group.