# Passing kwargs to Django URL and views

Tags: python, django

I would like to pass kwargs to my view function through URL.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [

# ------------- set relations --------------------
url(r'^approve-form/$', views.approve_form,
{'content_type':None, 'form_id':None,}, name='approve-form'),]
```

**views.py**

`def approve_form(request, content_type=None, form_id=None):
    return  HttpResponse('Working')`

Now I am using `reverse_lazy` function to call the url from on of the model instance

**models.py**

```
class FormStatus(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    form_id = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Form Ref ID')


    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.content_type)


    def get_approve_link(self):
        return  reverse_lazy("flow-control:approve-form", kwargs={'form_id':self.form_id,
                                                              'content_type':self.content_type})'
```

**ERROR**

```
Reverse for 'approve-form' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'content_type': <ContentType: admin sanc model>, 'form_id': 12}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['flow-control/approve-form/$']
```

Is something wrong with the approach or is there any better approach for this ?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I tried the [url documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions) but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: `flow-control` is `namespace` for the app(flow_control)  in which `approve-form` is named url. So I don't want to removed the namespace from it.

Comment: check with reverse function also , i'm sure you must have checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202385/django-reverse-with-arguments-and-keyword-arguments-not-found

Comment: @tom it seems that I need to specify mention them in url itself before passing them as kwargs. Thank you

Comment: I have updated my answer for this please check and upvote it also if you find it useful , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your url to and check if its worked or not-

```
   urlpatterns = [

   # ------------- set relations --------------------
  url(r'^approve-form/(?P<content_type>\w+)/(?P<form_id>\d+)/$', views.approve_form, name='approve-form'),]
```

**views**

```
 def approve_form(request, content_type=None, form_id=None):
     return  HttpResponse('Working')
```